# Python print same line

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can i print without "`\n`" and with parameters

Example:

Print this : `print("%d, %d" % (a, b))`
without newline

I tried this (but don't work): `print("%d, %d" % (a, b),end="")`

I have this :

```
  File "./test.py", line 9
    print("%d, %d" % (a, b), end="")
                                ^                           
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What did not work, did you get any errors?

Comment: I have this SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: You've tagged Python 3, but it sounds like you're using Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 2.x**:

```
from __future__ import print_function   # import the print func
print("{}, {}".format(1, 2), end="")   # 1, 2
```

**Python 3.x**:

```
print("{}, {}".format(1, 2), end="")   # 1, 2
```

Comment: don't work for me ..;

Comment: @APoorDev try the first one with `import` since it looks like you're using **Python 2.x**

Comment: @APoorDev did it work for you? If it did help you may accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score -2):

To print and end it with a special character

`print ('YOur message' , end = ' ')` the end is by default `\n` and can be overridden

and your message string will be`'{} {}'.format(a,b)`

Completing it to `print ('a = {}, b = {}'.format(a,b), end = ' ')`

[image]

Comment: not the question